# How to Order Coordinates in Matplotlib (xticks and yticks)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

Alright, so I was working on a simple program to just pull coordinates out of a text pad and then graph what was in the text pad on a graph. I thought it would be pretty simple, but I am VERY new to matplotlib, so I still don't fully understand. I got most of the code done correctly, but the only thing that is not working is that when I put the values in the graph, they come all out of order. I want to order the xticks and yticks so that it actually looks like a real line graph you'd see in math, so you can see how the lower coordinates lower than the higher coordinates, and vice versa. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def split(word): 
    return list(word) 
fileIWant = open('C:/Users/JustA/Desktop/Python Shenanigans/Converting Coordinates in a .txt to a Graph/Coordinates.txt', 'r');
stopwords = ['\n']
array = fileIWant.readlines()
array = [array.replace('\n', '') for array in array if array not in stopwords]
fileIWant.close()
editFile = open('C:/Users/JustA/Desktop/Python Shenanigans/Converting Coordinates in a .txt to a Graph/Coordinates.txt', 'w')
array_length = len(array)
x = []
y = []


for i in range(array_length):
    dataSplit = array[i].split()
    getCoordinateX = dataSplit[1]
    getCoordinateY = dataSplit[3]
    x.append(getCoordinateX)
    y.append(getCoordinateY)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.plot(x, y) #Add this line in if you want to show lines.
plt.title('Your Coordinate Graph')
plt.xlabel('X Coordinates')
plt.ylabel('Y Coordinates')
#plt.xticks([-100,-80,-60,-40,-20,0,20,40,60,80,100])
#plt.yticks([-100,-80,-60,-40,-20,0,20,40,60,80,100])
plt.show()
editFile.close()
```

I commented out what I put for the ticks, because it was not working at all. With those commented out, it looks okay, but it is very confusing. I think it just puts them in the order they are at in the .txt, when I want them to order themselves in the code. Here is what it is outputting right now: [image: This is what my graph looks like.]

Sorry if this is so simple that it has never been asked before, like I said, very new to matplotlib, and numpy if I have to use that at all. I imported it because I thought I may have to, but I don't think I really used it as of yet. Also, I am going to rewrite the coordinates into the graph in order, but I think I can do that myself later.

Comment: You forgot to convert your strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your coordinates are *strings*, which means matplotlib is just plotting strings against strings ("categorical" axis labels). To fix, you simply have to convert your strings to numbers, e.g. `x.append(int(getCoordinateX))`.

Note that you also don't have to put `plt.scatter`/`plt.plot` in the loop - you only have to call one of those once on the full array. That'll probably make things a little faster too.

Comment: Oh, I knew it would be something pretty simple. Thanks!